# Mongo db data encryption

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, encoding

I am going to store the secured data in mongodb. I chose mongo because it is easy to scale as I am expecting more fields to come in near future.
Please help me what is the best way to secure the data.

I can encode the data while sending as response via REST API. What is the best encoding algorithm. I am using laravel for rest API.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 4.2-compatible drivers offer [client side encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption/).

MongoDB server supports [encryption at rest](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/) and [transport encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-transport-encryption/).